# Finding the basis of its kernel of $T([x, y, z]^T)=x-2y-3z$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the linear map$:T:\mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}$ with
>   $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}\right)=x-2y-3z$$
>   Find the basis of its kernel.

**My try**

Since the plane is the nullspace of the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

But I am stuck here. Can anyone explain this furthur

Comment: You can't find **the** basis, you can find **a** basis.

Comment: why consider a 3x3 matrix when $T\colon \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: You seem to have understood that the kernel is a plane. Can you find two non-zero elements of it? If they are not multiples of each other then you will have your basis.

Comment: you have to find 2 linearly independent solutions to $x-2y-3z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "kernel" of a linear transformation, $A$, is defined as the subspace, $\{v\}$, of its domain such that $Av= 0$.  Here that is $A(x, y, z)= x- y+ 3z= 0$.  We can solve for $x$: for any $y, z$, $x= y- 3z$.  A vector in the kernel is of the form $(x, y, z)=(y- 3z, y, z)= (y, y, 0)+ (-3z, 0, z)= y(1, 1, 0)+ z(-3, 0, 1)$.  A basis for the kernel is ${(1, 1, 0), (-3, 0, 1)}$.

Comment: So, I need to set the equation $x-2y-3z=0$ and  got $x=2y+3z$ and as you said $A(x,y,z)=(2y+3z,y,z)$

Comment: But how did you get $x=y-3z$? I got $x=2y+3z$

Comment: Because I misread the equation!

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=1$ and solve $0=x-2y-3z$ for $y$ with $z=0$ and vice versa. Once you have found $y',z'$ satisfying $0=1-2y'$ and $0=1-3z'$, then you know that $f(1,y',0)=f(1,0,z')=0$ and so you have two vectors in the kernel of $f$. Verify that they are linearly independent. Finally, as $\dim(\Bbb R^3)=\dim(Im(f))+\dim(\ker(f))$, we have $\dim(\ker(f))=2$ and so the vectors form a basis.

Answer (score 0):

The Kernel of $T$ is a two dimensional space.

You need to find two linearly independent vectors satisfying $$ x-2y-3z=0 $$

Finding such vectors is achieved by choosing $x$ and $y$ values and solving for $z$

I have found $(3,0,1)$ and $(0,3,-2)$ to serve as a basis for the kernel of T.

Comment: But I got a different answer. My attempt:- $A(x,y,z)=x-2y-3z=0$ and $x=2y+3z$          $(2y+3z,y,z)=(2y,y,0)+(3z,0,z)$                                                                                     $=y(2,1,0)+z(3,0,1)$

Comment: @philip It is perfectly OK.  The basis vectors are not unique. Any set of two linearly independent vectors  in the kernel constitutes a basis for the kernel.

Comment: So what I got was correct, right?

Comment: @philip  Yes your solution is correct.